# return Dictonary from Objective c file to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, opencv, nsdictionary

I am working with open cv and swift. While returning `NSDictionary` from Objective-C file to Swift getting an error.

```
2018-10-10 12:43:25.972927+0530 OPencvwithSwift[2430:618249] -[__NSFrozenDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c022b6e0
2018-10-10 12:43:25.973704+0530 OPencvwithSwift[2430:618249] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSFrozenDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c022b6e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183eb6d8c 0x1830705ec 0x183ec4098 0x183ebc5c8 0x183da241c 0x1053c23d4 0x105360aa0 0x10585294c 0x104aec9a0 0x104ae287c 0x105cd51dc 0x105cd519c 0x105cd9d2c 0x183e5f070 0x183e5cbc8 0x183d7cda8 0x185d62020 0x18dd9c758 0x104af984c 0x18380dfc0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is Objective c code -

```
- (NSDictionary *)predict:(UIImage*)img confidence:(double)confidence {

    cv::Mat src = [img cvMatRepresentationGray];
    int label;
    NSLog(@"%d",label);
    std::cout<<_labelsDictionary;
    self->_faceClassifier->predict(src, label, confidence);
    NSLog(@"%f",confidence);
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:confidence] forKey:_labelsDictionary[@(label)]];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    return dict;
}
```

Calling this function from Swift:

```
let result = facemodel?.predict(greyimage, confidence: confidence) // crash on this line
```

Comment: Which line is causing the crash exactly? It seems that at some point your are using a `NSDictionary` as it was a `NSString` (which implements the `-length`) or something similar.

Comment: I edited the que

Answer (score 0):

Your application crash while executing Objective-C method probably. Use break point inside Objective-C method and continue step-by-step so you will find your crash.

There is no way to crash assign pretict method's return dict to result variable. It gives [AnyHashable: Any] to result, so you will have a [AnyHashable: Any] type result object.

Comment: its works on returning part and when it come back to swift function it crashes.

Comment: @neerajsachdeva did you try break point?. after your dict break point step away, point will skip "let result = ***" line. so maybe problem is with your dict variable. can you give me more spesific detail like "when a click skip on xcode debug after "return dict;" it crashed"

Comment: function completely executed but after goes into swift file it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, before you use the dictionary,In other places it has been pointed to a string. so crash